# Multiple logging managers for different services, or one with multiple databases (graylog)

Tags: docker, logging, graylog, centralized-logging

I am creating a logging infrastructure for a company with 2 unrelated services. Is it better to have:

- a single graylog instance that routes the logs from the two services
  to different elasticsearch databases
- or rather have two separate graylog instances running in 2 docker
  containers with their own elasticsearch clusters

I only have 1 server available for the logging stuff, there is not a huge volume of logs from either source.

I am not super experienced with server admin so I'm looking for advice for which might cause more headaches - having to deal with more complicated routing, certificates and port stuff or have all log files running through the same place and having to strictly separate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend setting up one OpenSearch cluster (because OpenSearch is [recommended by GrayLog](https://go2docs.graylog.org/5-0/downloading_and_installing_graylog/installing_graylog.html)) and one Graylog instance: Then, you can route the logs to different streams and grant permissions accordingly.

By doing so, you'll only have to configure/update one Graylog and one OpenSearch cluster.